# JD2XX Java FTDI library - Where can I get it from?

Tags: java, usb, ftdi

I'm thinking of writing a little program for my SDR-14 software radio
using Java and had a look
around for a Java library to communicate with the SDR's FTDI USB interface IC. A
quick Google finds loads of mentions of the JD2XX library which used
to be at ..

https://jd2xx.dev.java.net/

Except that that page now gives a 404 error so I wonder if that
project was deleted or left that domain following the Oracle take over
of Sun.

Does anyone know where this project has gone and where I can
download the library from ?

Regards

Ian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The project was evidently lost in the recent (or not so recent) java.net upgrade. The last reasonable archive I found with the source for the project is (oddly enough) at http://fred.bilinski.it/src/Fred-20050525.zip so you may want to download that and archive it. It has the source for the jd2xx classes and the jd2xx dll (not sure whether the dll is 32-bit or 64-bit) but these are dated from 2005, so you might want to reach out to http://bleyer.org/jd2xx/ and see if you can get more recent updates.

Alternatively you may want to look at http://sourceforge.net/projects/ftd2xxj/ which appears to be more recent.

Answer (score 2):

It seems he has made a SourceForge project as well: http://sourceforge.net/projects/d2xx/

And the files can be found in the SVN repository: http://d2xx.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/d2xx/